# Rotation of ellipsoid(quadric)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, surfaces, rotations, quadrics

Consider $$φ(x, y , z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 4z^2 −xy −2xz −3yz$$
find the coordinate transformation (translation or rotation) to eliminate $xy$, $xz$ and $yz$.
In $\mathbb R²$, with conic sections, I would do this with 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha &-\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix}$$

to find the rotation angle. But how is it done with quadrics?

Comment: For a conic, how would you determine the required angle $\alpha$?

Comment: sorry I took so long to answer, ran out of connection.. for the conic $$Ax^2+By^2+Cxy+D$$
I would consider the rotation in the OP: $x=x'cos\alpha-y'sen\alpha, y= x'sen\alpha + y'cos\alpha$<br>
then the equation, in respect to the rotated base would be
$$A(x'cos\alpha-y'sen\alpha)^2+B(x'sen\alpha + y'cos\alpha)^2+C(x'cos\alpha-y'sen\alpha)(x'sen\alpha + y'cos\alpha)$$
$$\implies A(x'^2cos^2\alpha+y'^2sin^2\alpha)+B(x'^2sen^2\alpha+y'^2cos^2\alpha)-2Ax'y'sin\alpha cos\alpha+2Bx'y'sin\alpha cos\alpha+Cx'y' cos^2\alpha-Cx'y'sen^2\alpha+C(x'^2sen\alpha cos\alpha-y'^2sen\alpha cos\alpha)$$

Comment: $$\implies A(x'^2cos^2\alpha+y'^2sin^2\alpha)+B(x'^2sen^2\alpha+y'^2cos^2\alpha)+x'y'(-2Asin\alpha cos\alpha+2Bsin\alpha cos\alpha+Ccos^2\alpha-Csen^2\alpha)+C(x'^2sen\alpha cos\alpha-y'^2sen\alpha cos\alpha)$$
to eliminate the mixed term,
$$-2Asin\alpha cos\alpha+2Bsin\alpha cos\alpha+Ccos^2\alpha-Csen^2\alpha=0$$
$$\implies(B-A)sin2\alpha+Ccos2\alpha=0
\implies cotg2\alpha=\frac {A-B} C\implies\alpha=\frac {arccotg(\frac{A-B} C)}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

\begin{align}
\phi(x,y,z) &= x^2 -x(y+2z)+{(y+2z)^2\over 4} -{(y+2z)^2\over 4}+ 2y^2 + 4z^2  −3yz\\
& = (x-{y+2z\over 2})^2+{7\over 4}y^2+3z^2-4yz\\
& = {1\over 4}(2x-y-2z)^2+{1\over 12}(36z^2-48yz+21y^2)\\
& = {1\over 4}(2x-y-2z)^2+{1\over 12}((6z)^2-2 \cdot4y\cdot 6z+16y^2+5y^2)\\
& = {1\over 4}(2x-y-2z)^2+{1\over 12}(6z-4y)^2+{5\over 12}y^2\\
& = {1\over 4}(2x-y-2z)^2+{1\over 3}(3z-2y)^2+{5\over 12}y^2
\end{align}

$$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\ y'\\z' \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1/2&-1\\
0 &\sqrt{5\over 12}&0\\
0 &-2\over \sqrt{3}& 3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\\z \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: you might be interested to look at my edits, which helped line up your equations nicely.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHughes

Comment: I don’t quite see how this helps since the transformation you derived isn’t an isometry or even close to one.

Comment: Why do you need isometry?

Comment: And how do you know it even exist?

Comment: From the question: “... find the coordinate transformation (*translation or rotation*)...” [emphasis mine]. There is always an orthogonal diagonalization of a quadratic form. That’s basically the principal axis theorem.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to 'see' it, given $\varphi(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+4z^2-xy-2xz-3yz$, you can also write this as $u^{\top}Qu$ for $u=(x,y,z)$ and 
\begin{equation}
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -0.5 & -1\\
-0.5 & 2 & -1.5\\
-1 & -1.5 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\succ 0
\end{equation}
Then diagonalize $Q$, i.e. $Q=T\Lambda T^{\top}$, where now $u^{\top}Q u = u^{\top}T\Lambda T^{\top}u$, for $\Lambda$ diagonal, such that $T^{\top}$ is your desired transformation.

Comment: `[T,LAMBDA]=eig(Q)` in matlab gives `T'*Q*T`=`LAMBDA` or $\begin{pmatrix}    0.7558  &  0.5207 &   0.3971\\
    0.6318  & -0.7392  & -0.2332\\
   -0.1721  & -0.4271  &  0.8877\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&-\frac12&-1\\-\frac12&2&-\frac32\\-1&-\frac32&4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0.7558  &  0.6318  & -0.1721\\
    0.5207 &  -0.7392 &  -0.4271\\
    0.3971  & -0.2332  &  0.8877\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.1301&0&0\\0&1.9541&0\\0&0&4.9157\end{pmatrix}$.